# Vertx connection pooling issue, high value of vertx_sql_queue_pending

Tags: postgresql, connection-pooling, vert.x, vertx4

I am very new to Vertx, so please excuse me if this is a very basic question. I am facing issues with Vertx connection pool, I am using `io.vertx:vertx-pg-client` with Vertx version 4.2.7.

After sometime, application is not able to get a connection from the pool. We looked at a couple of metrics and we found `vertx_sql_queue_pending` high value aligns with the connection pool issue.

Why there are pending Jobs?

- Do I need to increase connection count?
- Any other resource which I need to increase to fix this issue?

Basically, I am not very sure what the exact issue is and how do I solve it.

Comment: Are you sure connections are returned to the pool after usage? A snippet of how you make queries would be helpful. Then you can check if sessions are busy by running `select * from pg_stat_activity where application_name like '%vertx%'  and state = 'active'`

Comment: Hi @tsegismont Thanks for the response!! I am now executing query directly on the pool, so I am not handling the connection directly, the connections should be handled internally by the pool.

Comment: OK. What about the results from `pg_stat_activity`?